# React-native TextInput crash

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, crash

Ok... So here is the probelem.

I am new to react-native, so I'm probably missing something simple, but whenever I run the slightly modified Hello World app, it crashes with an error reading

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.graphics.drawable.Drawable$ConstantState.newDrawable(android.content.res.Resources)' on a null object reference
```

Here is the source causing this crash for me

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello world!</Text>
        <TextInput></TextInput>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Ok, so I updated npm re-installed the project and it still crashed. However, after I restarted Expo on my phone, it started working again. I'm not sure what happened but it appears it may have been an issue with my slightly old npm version and then Expo hung onto that error until I forced it to restart.

Just an idea, but it's the best I have. I'll update if things change.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Seems like an open issue [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17530)

Answer (score 2):

The TextInput crash was reported in the **react-native version 0.56** and it was resolved in **react-native version 0.57**

Please refer the changelog of react-native 0.57 in the following link.

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#057

I'm suggesting to upgrade your react-native versions.

Comment: I am using react-native 0.61.5. but I still have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may be due to the `TextInput` not having an appropriate closing tag.

```
<TextInput />
```

Comment: I edited your answer to provide some clarity, however, either I'm not understanding the nature of your answer or it is not correct, i.e. `<TextInput> ... </TextInput>` as shown in the OP's question appears to be correct. Could you provide some clarification?

Comment: You're correct, this is not the answer. My answer should've been just a comment on the original question

Answer (score 0):

The following resolved it for me:

1. Reset packager and clear its cache. (R)
2. Clear cache on your Expo app too.
3. Restart app.